# No print output on raspberry IDLE

Tags: python, process

I've been trying to create a program that split few different section of my main OpenCV program to increase fps. The first thing i ever think of is the Pipe() function from my friend. I've tried this 'default' code below in python 2.7 on Windows 10 to learn the basic first of multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(conn):
    conn.send([42, None, 'hello'])
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print (parent_conn.recv())   # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

After that i went to Raspberry Python 3 to do the same thing, but nothing happen in Python console when i tried to run it.

the console cursor just sit there doing nothing beside blinking, but when i try to run it from terminal by typing `Python` and followed by file directory, the text just appear like nothing happen.

I don't know why, but i'm definitely missing something here. can i actually run this on Python 3? and why the text are not shown in Console that called from IDLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sort. No, you cannot modify IDLE easy enough without dismantle IDLE core code or something. Instead, you can use Geany (in raspberry or linux stuff) or Notepad++ with your own RUN-command.

But with a drawback, even this is not in the scope of question. See, the Geany and Notepad++ is only for printing stuff in multiprocessing or multithreading code. It's not mean to be a debugger or some sort.